# How to use Google Oauth2 for both signing in users and creating new user accounts in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm working on google authentication for a rails app. Currently using the [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) gem to implement Google auth. I've managed to have users sign in using google. However, I'd also like users to be able to sign up using google. My problem is that I've matched the google callback URL to a particular controller action (sessions#create).
Is it possible to choose between 2 redirect URIs based on whether users are signing in or signing up? Currently, my only idea is to create new google client credentials to be used for sign up, I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have 2 redirect uris, you just need to do some more work when receiving the callback. For instance:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    email = auth_hash['info']['email'] # assuming your omniauth hash is auth_hash and you're requiring the email scope
    @user = User.find_by(email: email) if !email.blank? # assuming your user model is User

    if @user
      login_user(@user) # use your login method
    elsif !email.blank?
      @user = User.new(name: auth_hash['info']['name'], email: email) 
      unless @user.save!(validate: false) # validate false because I'm enforcing passwords on devise - hence I need to allow passwordless register here)
          # deal with error on saving
      end
    else
      # deal with no found user and no email
    end
  end

  protected

    def auth_hash
        request.env['omniauth.auth']
    end

end
```

I've written all steps but the creation process can be shortened to:

```
@user = User.create_with(name: auth_hash['info']['name']).find_or_initialize_by(email: email)
@user.save! if @user.new_record?
if @user 
  login_user(@user)
else 
  # deal with no user
end
```

Nonetheless, you can't be sure the user is going to give you scope access to the email, so personally I think the first version, even if a bit lengthier is more robust. Then on the shorter version there's also the problem of, `if @user` is false, why is so? And will require you to add more logic to figure out why is that, whereas in the first one it's much easier to apply the correct response to each situation.